# Trying to run a query on postgreSQL that displays the following:

Tags: postgresql, kaggle

I've loaded a dataset from Kaggle onto postgreSQL. This data set was created to list all shows available on Paramount streaming. I'm trying to display only the row with the title that has the highest vote count per year for the past decade (2012-2022).

So far, I was only able to display and order the titles based on the timeframe of interest (2012-2022).
[What I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhwU6.jpg)

As you see in the image, I only want what I manually highlighted in yellow to show for each year in the past decade.

Comment: Please don't post images. Provide code in a format that can be easily edited. The question itself has an off-by-one error: the past decade is 2013-2022 not 2012-2022 (that covers 11 years).

Comment: It always advised to provide script to reproduce the requirement and possible output instead of uploading image. What I can understand from your post is to list the highest rating show in each year based on the the imdb_votes column. You can try the window function for this.
`with cte_stream_list
(
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY release_year ORDER BY imdb_votes DESC) AS rnk
FROM paramount
WHERE release_year >= 2012 AND release_year <= 2022
) 
SELECT * FROM cte_stream_list WHERE rnk = 1;`
Try this.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 0):

If it where guaranteed that only one movie in a release year would receive the highest number of votes, then the following query would work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (release_year), *
  FROM paramount
  WHERE release_year BETWEEN 2013 AND 2022
  ORDER BY release_year DESC, imdb_votes DESC;
```

Unfortunately, more than one movie in a release year could tie for the highest number of votes. The following query addresses this possibility:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT *,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY release_year ORDER BY imdb_votes DESC) AS rank
    FROM paramount
)
SELECT *
  FROM ranked
  WHERE rank = 1
    AND release_year BETWEEN 2013 and 2022
  ORDER BY release_year DESC, title;
```